# Load CSV into Redshift, with header?

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, etl

Is there an option to load a CSV into Redshift with a header? I see the documentation for CSV but it says nothing about a header. Ideally it could use the header to determine the columns to load.

Comment: With CSV the header is not helpful, but if you are using JSON is more descriptive : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use the `IGNOREHEADER 1` option when using the [`COPY`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) command:

> IGNOREHEADER [ AS ] *number_rows*
>
> Treats the specified *number_rows* as a file header and does not load them. Use IGNOREHEADER to skip file headers in all files in a parallel load.

See: [Amazon Redshift `COPY` command documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html)

Comment: Is there any way to have it use the header for knowing which columns to load? Ideally I could just say LOAD mytable FROM myfile.csv USING HEADER FOR COLUMNS, or something like that.

Comment: No, the Header will not be used to identify columns. You must provide column names as part of the COPY command and they will be loaded in the order provided in the file.

Comment: It was clear from the dococ but after experimenting I found the format is `COPY schema.table FROM.... CREDENTIALS...... IGNOREHEADER 1`. Don't forget the 1 (to skip one row)

Comment: A tool I wrote will create a table for you based on the CSV column headers, but Redshift alone doesn't know how to create a table based on a CSV you hand it: https://github.com/bluelabsio/records-mover

(to be fair, I'm not sure if OP was looking to only load certain columns (and leave the rest NULL?) or create the table.)